# Trailing slash URL page broken (Even though 200 status code appears)

Tags: .htaccess

http://www.customlogoshop.com/logo-design/ won't load properly. Removing trailing slash leads to the working page.

I need to redirect trailing slash to http://www.customlogoshop.com/logo-design.

Here is my current htaccess

```html
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymlinks

<Files .htaccess>
deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine on




RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f

RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]




</IfModule>
```

Comment: So the problem is a 500 status is returning on your resource files, such as the folder css and js

Comment: http://www.customlogoshop.com/css/app.css works for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this code in `logo-design` html code `<head>`:

```
<base href="/">
```

or

```
<base href="http://www.customlogoshop.com/">
```

Because without `/` with `http://www.customlogoshop.com/logo-design` with `css/` relative link, you read:
`http://www.customlogoshop.com/css/`

But with `/`you read: `http://www.customlogoshop.com/logo-design/css/`

You also can add absolute path or `/` before all the relative links.

You can redirect trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ /$1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /([^\ ]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)\.php$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Done and it works! What about duplicate content issues?

Comment: You can add in your `<head>`: `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.customlogoshop.com/logo-design/">` or you can redirect 301 without `/`.

Comment: I add redirect 301 without `/` in my answer.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much. I've wasted so much time trying to figure this out! Thank you!